# how to begin software and web development?

Tags: web-applications, cross-platform

I am quite familiar with programming languages(I know basics of Java, c++, Python, JavaScript, Ruby, Html, CSS). I have created some simple apps in Java(Android Studio) and Python(Kivy).
I now want to become a serious developer and start developing real nice cross-platform applications and web-applications, but I am not able to decide which is the best tool for these purposes. If necessary I have no problem in learning a new programming language.
Also, I am a student of Electrical and Electronics Engineering(2nd year) and apart from learning Java(in school and 1st year of college) rest I learned online. So I lack proper guidance on how to go about being a software developer.
Please! can someone help me?

Comment: It's a fine question, but this is not where you should be asking it. StackOverflow is for technical programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a professional developer for 10 years now and it all started with web development. I remember starting out with a similar skill set as you, no specialty, just a broad understanding of basic programming.

Here's a site I used to use and from time to time still do as reference material. https://www.w3schools.com. Do the courses and you'll feel like an expert within a day. Best of all, it's free.

Once you learn the basics, you need to decide what web technology you want to specialise on. I went with the Microsoft way and I would recommend it to any starting developer just so they can land a job quicker. Learn C#, do ASP.Net Core and host in Azure. Here's their documentation site, https://learn.microsoft.com

Once you get the feel of it. Time to start thinking architecture. Architecture for a developer at its simplest is just a good way to organise code, project and services so that it's easier to get the next guy looking at your work get started regardless of the size of the solution. Good architecture basically makes you dispensable. I would recommend reading up on Domain Driven Development. I've come across many different kinds of architecture but they all look like DDD to me.

That's probably all for now. Good luck and most importantly, have fun.

Comment: thanks for helping.